# Ruby class that validates a string

Tags: ruby

I have this class that needs to do three things:

- Determine if a string is 8 characters or longer
- Determine if a string has a number in it
- Determine if a string has a capital letter in it

NB: **I don't want to use regex**. Is there a better way of doing this?

```
class ValidateString
  def initialize(string)
    @string = string

    if valid 
      puts @string 
    end
  end

  def valid
    if has_number? and has_upper? and has_length?
      return @string
    end
  end

  def has_number?
    @string.count("0-9") > 0
  end

  def has_upper?
    @string =~ /[A-Z]/
  end

  def has_length?
    @string.length >= 8
  end
end
```

Comment: Why not use regex? It's sounds like a valid solution for this

Comment: (And you are already using regex in `has_upper?` by the way)

Comment: Are you checking for password strength? Obligatory [XKCD](https://xkcd.com/936/)

Answer (score 2):

- `ValidateString` is strange name for a class. `StringValidator` would be more apt.
- Don't make your constructor print anything. Your class exists to validate a string, not print things to stdout. Leave that to some other piece of code.
- `valid` should be named `valid?` and return a boolean. And you can omit the `return` keyword.
- Add `attr_reader :string`, and replace your `@string` with just `string`
- `8` is a magic number, and should be replaced with constant (e.g. `MIN_STRING_LENGTH`)
- Presumably, this exists to check for simple passwords. However, you're not checking that the string contains *both* upper- and lowercase letters. An all-uppercase string with a number would pass validation. For passwords, you'd want to enforce that it's *mixed* casing.

I'd just write a method:

```
def valid_string?(string)
  return false unless string.length >= 8
  return false unless string =~ /[0-9]/
  return false unless string =~ /[[:upper:]]/ # allows non-Latin letters
  return false unless string =~ /[[:lower:]]/ # ditto
  true
end
```

Of course, you'd be better off using something like [`zxcvbn`](https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn) to check password entropy. Your rules allow for the good ol' `Password1` string just fine.

Comment: "8 is a magic number, and should be replaced with constant (e.g. MIN_STRING_LENGTH)"
Could you elaborate on this?
Everything else makes perfect sense to me. I'm still learning the appropriate time to use constants. Why exactly should the 8 alone not be used?

Comment: @fight_dragons Because `8` by itself isn't very explanatory, whereas `MIN_STRING_LENGTH` makes it clear what you're doing. Granted, this isn't a terrible case, since the context makes it clear enough ("ok, string has to be at least 8 chars long, got it"), but still. If in doubt: Use a constant. Any arbitrary number you use in your code should be "labelled" by making it a constant. It keeps the code much more maintainable.

Comment: `return false unless string =~ /[[:lower:]]` is not asked in the specification, your function incorrectly rejects `12345689X` that should be accepted.

Comment: @Caridorc Read my answer again; the last point in particular. I'm well aware I'm making an assumption about the code's purpose.

Comment: @Flambino yup I had missed that, fair point

Answer (score 0):

@Flambino 's answer can be simplified by using a simple `&&` (`and`) instead of `return false unless` (I also removed the extra condition):

```
def valid_string?(string)
  string.length >= 8       && \     
  string =~ /[0-9]/        && \
  string =~ /[[:upper:]]/ 
end
```